# Page caching by the browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer

I'm trying to debug how IE caches page data (such as `input` and `textarea`) in the browser history.

**Navigation sequence:**

Page1 with `textarea`  -> user navigates to Page2 -> goes back to Page1 and `textarea` data is repopulated by the browser

If the user injects malicious code into the `textarea`, it gets evaluated by the angular and leads to XSS attack.

My objective is to sanitize the data before it gets stored in the browser history. Any leads to understanding this will be helpful.

Comment: edited to make it more clear. Please justify the question for -1

Comment: Please review your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Also add code. See [ask], which makes basic requirements fairly plain.

Comment: Also, IE? in 2022?? [A Business Case for Dropping Internet Explorer](https://css-tricks.com/a-business-case-for-dropping-internet-explorer/)

Comment: Why is angular evaluating the textarea content to begin with? _"and leads to XSS attack."_ - users "attacking" _themselves_ aren't usually a thing I'd worry about too much. "Real" XSS is if _I_ could get it to execute code when _you_ are viewing the page in your browser, and that does not appear to be the case here in this scenario.

Comment: @CBroe , it is evaluated because of interpolation. Read more about the issue [here](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2022-25869)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't got any official docs that could specify how exactly IE stores the field data to cache. Here are some articles you could refer to get some information about the topic.

1. [Understanding Microsoft Internet Explorer Cache](https://www.digital-detective.net/understanding-microsoft-internet-explorer-cache/)
2. [Ie caching form data](https://zditect.com/blog/2313607.html)

Further, I didn't find any document that explain the caching deeply at field level.

I understand that you want to sanitize the data before it get cached. I would suggest validation of those fields may help to prevent user inserting the malicious code.

Comment: the question is about understanding how the browser caches the fields.

Comment: @ScrapCode, please check the updated answer. It may help you get some helpful information.